# Javascript component for visually mapping items in one list to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a html/javascript/browser based component for mapping items in one list to another. Picture a list of items on the left hand side, another list on the right, and the ability to click on an item from the left hand side, then click on one from the right hand side, thus connecting/associating them (it doesn't literally have to work that way; you get the idea).

It should work well across IE6+ and FF/Chrome/Safari, and if it's a jQuery extension that's even better.

Anybody know of good options?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

JsPlumb is interesting as well to emulate "connectors".

http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/jquery/chartDemo.html
http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/doc/usage.html